# Sort a dictionary by key, and then take values from a particular key

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have some storm data that I've sorted into dictionaries, with the **key** being the year the storm occurred. The **value** of the main dictionary is actually another dictionary, with the storm name as the **key** for the inner dictionary.

After I've created all the dictionaries, I ask the user for an input, and store that input as the variable `year` which gets passed to the function that I want to use to display the data, let's call it `display_info(dictionary, year)`.

Sidenote: I have a `main()` function that actually takes the input for year, and other functions that edit and return the dictionary, so what I have here isn't complete, it's just this one function that I need help with.

```
year = input("Input a year: ")

def display_info(dictionary, year):
    '''Displays the storm info for the year input'''

    for k,v in dictionary.items():     
        if k == year:
            print(k, v)
```

I've tried a few different variations of this, but none seem to get the job done.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: `input` returns a string, are the keys in your dictionary `int`s?  You can just use the normal dictionary lookup to access the value of a key in a dictionary: `dictionary[year]`

Comment: [Works on my machine](https://ideone.com/lQ0Rk1). (assuming those indentation errors aren't in your original code)

Comment: Sorry, re-read this and realzied the questions wasn't very clear! I want to know how to look up a particular key (the year that is input) and then only print the values from that key.

Comment: @Marty Looks like alexis has  you covered

Comment: I made some edits to fix the indentation errors; they were not present in my actual code, yet it still would not work. I checked the dictionary by printing it before the "for" statement, as well as the year, to make sure the variables were passed from one function to this one, and both of them print as they should. For some reason, the "for" statement doesn't like it.

Comment: I think I may know why it's not working... when I print the dictionary, the key has quotes around the year, such as '2009' instead of just the number... Can that just be stripped out of the dictionary when i create the key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Id just do:

```
if year in dictionary:
   print(year, dictionary[year])
```

also, if your dictionary keys consist of type `int`, you will need to something like:

```
year = int(year)
```

before running that logic.

I would not do:

`int(input())` because if you input something non numeric it will raise a `ValueError`

Further exploiting `.get()`, which has a second argument which can be used to assign default values, you could just do:

```
print(year, dictionary.get(year, 'No entry found for year: %s' % year)
```

This would print 'No entry found for year x' if the key (year) is missing from the dictionary.

Comment: You're not using the return value; `if year in dictionary` is more Pythonic.

Comment: Because I'd like the user to learn .get, I also provided another use where he could use .get and reduce the logic to one line.

Comment: But, I updated the answer to make use of your example, also providing a .get() example.

Comment: I think .get was one of the hints that was given a while back for stuff like this, so it most likely is the way that it should be done. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, if this worked please mark the answer as correct :) Wish you a nice day!